# The type 'NotificationsExtensions.*' exists in both '...\NotificationsExtensions.winmd' and '...\NotificationsExtensions.winmd'

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm just starting to get to know Windows RT programming. I want to try notifications, so I downloaded the [App tiles and badges sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969156.aspx), extracted the NotificationExtensions project to my solution and tried to compile, but it won't do so because of the following compilation error:

```
The type 'NotificationsExtensions.*' exists in both
'...\NotificationsExtensions.winmd' and '...\NotificationsExtensions.winmd'
```

The two .winmd file paths are perfectly identical, that is what baffles me!

I even tried to compile the sample solution as is, but I got the same error for each and every reference to types in the NotificationExtensions library.

I'm running a Windows 8 Release Preview in VirtualBox with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RTM (evaluation only). Could this issue have something to do with the fact that the Preview contains a different version of .NET 4.5 than that which the VS 2012 RTM requires? (I had to alter the version number of the .NET installation in the registry to allow VS to install.) Do I have to upgrade to Windows 8 RTM because of this?

Thanks in advance!

gLes

Comment: Mixing and matching of versions is not supported:  if you are using the Visual Studio 2012 RTM, you must also use the Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis you should move your comment to an answer.  gLes, the VS 2012 Release Candidate could be used with Windows 8 RP, but I wasn't able to locate it last night on the web.  With the Windows 8 GA imminent, they may have pulled it.  The Sample code is all updated to GA though anyway.

Comment: The RP is functional until mid January 2013. I guess I'm going to upgrade to the RTM (for which also exists a 90 day trial).